# Authenticate .net web application as specific user

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis-8, webpack-dev-server

I have a .net mvc web application running on a domain and it uses windows authentication.

I was looking into react redux and webpack-server. It is possible to run 2 servers. One is the .net web app and the other is the webpack-server that will serve the java scripts with hot loading and other goodies.

To have webpack-server serve content from the .net application I can add the following:

```
proxy: {
  '*': {
    target: 'http://other-server.example.com'
  }
}
```

Any request for a missing resource will go to the .net application. This however does not work because the authentication does not work.

Is it possible to have a build profile that does web.config transformations that will set any request to authenticate as a certain user?

Or does anyone know how node server can proxy requests supporting windows authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The sollution I found was the following:

In the global.asax.cs

```
    protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
        {
            if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["anonymous"] == "true")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("DOMAIN\\Harry-Potter"), new string[] { });
            }
        }
    }
```

Created a build profile with Build => configuration manager.. => (under Active solution configuration is a dropdown where you can add new)

Right click web.config and choose "add config transform"

In web.[your profile].config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="anonymous" value="true" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

Transformations to the web.config with web.debug.config and web.[my build profile].config do not apply untill you publish for some reason. To have the transformation available every time you build you can do the following.

Copy web.config to web.base (web.base does not exist so just do `copy web.config web.base`

Open your web application csproj file (same directory as web.config and web.base) add/edit the following 2 lines at the end.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>"$(MSBUILDBINPATH)\msbuild" "$(ProjectPath)" /t:Transform /p:Configuration=$(ConfigurationName);Platform=AnyCPU</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target> -->
  <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="Transform">
    <MakeDir Directories="bin" Condition="!Exists('bin')" />
    <TransformXml Source="Web.base" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" StackTrace="true" />
  </Target>
```

In web.base:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="anonymous" value="false" />
```

The web.config will be re written every time you build.

Now when you switch build profiles you can either have the real user or a mock user identity for the application (can be convenient for testing other user profiles as well).

In C:\Users[my user]\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config

I changed some settings to allow anonymous, if not the IIS express will not let anonymous users.

```
<anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" userName="" />
```